# Query Using PDO in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, codeigniter-3

I just try using CI V3.1.9 connecting to MySQL Server and retrieve the data. How about using PDO as the driver?

How to fetch the data? Because my query always return whitespace.

Here is my database.php

```
'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname:db_dms;',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => 'user',
'password' => '123',
'database' => 'db_dms',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

Here is my controller.php

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['bError'] = false;
        $data['sErrorMessage'] = '';

        $this->load->model("ModPengguna");

        if(isset($_POST['btnLogin']))
        {
            $result = $this->db->conn_id->prepare("select * from m_user where userID = ? and pass = ?");

            //binding option using PDO
            $result->bindValue(1, 'SUPERADM01', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindValue(2, '123', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            print_r($result->result());

            //I also tried this
            print_r($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fetch the data?

Thanks.

Comment: please read this https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62163.html

Comment: hi @hamedhossani, thanks for your URL. I just solved it.. miss typo at the database.php ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname:db_dms;'). it should be 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_dms;'